# Broadcast Receivers in Delphi XE5 Android

Tags: android, delphi, broadcastreceiver

How to use broadcast receivers in Delphi XE5 Android? The documentation is very poor about the Delphi XE5 and Android integration.

Comment: @LURD - why not posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no support in XE5 for broadcast receivers.

It is needed in order to get the BlueTooth API implemented, for example.
Some attempts can be found [`here`](http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html).

**Update:**

Markus Humm filed two QC requests to get this working.

[`QC 118435 Provide the ability to inherit from a Java class`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118435) and

[`QC 118683 Provide Delphi side implementation for Android.BluetoothAdapter`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118683).

Vote for them!

Comment: FYI, 2 broadcast receivers are implemented in my service sample at http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services-part-2.html

Comment: @blong, nice work. I will study the examples and see if there is a possibility to get Bluetooth communication working.

Comment: It should quite feasible, if slightly tricky.
It has been on my to do list to get the Bluetooth Chat sample kinda ported over, but haven't had opportunity thus far...

Answer (score 1):

I've written a BroadcastReceiver plug-in for Delphi XE5 that provides such support. The plug-in does everything required to support BroadcastReceiver development during run-time.

See http://chuacw.ath.cx/blogs/chuacw/archive/2014/02/26/delphi-ide-broadcastreceiver-plug-in-for-android.aspx